# Why is 5MB the limit for the block length?

Tags: polkadot, block, block-size

The length limit for each block in Polkadot is set to 5Mb as seen [in the code](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/e6fa871e39bab8ccec27070b3b93a2e5e50ff0a4/runtime/common/src/lib.rs#L112).

But why exactly 5Mb? Could you point me to the decision process or the benchmark results for that exact value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formal definition and reasoning can be found in W3F's Polkadot spec, specifically Definition 158 on Block Limits:

- https://spec.polkadot.network/#defn-polkadot-block-limits

And more info from Web3 Foundation's research can be found here:

- https://research.web3.foundation/en/latest/polkadot/overview/2-token-economics.html#limits-on-resource-usage

Comment: I was aware of the first [link](https://spec.polkadot.network/#defn-polkadot-block-limits)(but it didn't show any reasoning for it), but the [second](https://research.web3.foundation/en/latest/polkadot/overview/2-token-economics.html#limits-on-resource-usage) gives more insights about that and other specific parameters. Thanks.